# Custom child component not rendered in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a custom Ionic component, let's say "<child>" trying to include it in a "<parent>" component by simply inserting the child selector tag in the parent HTML. However, when I navigate to the parent, the child component is not rendered. I know that I have to import a module for the child when I am lazy-loading the parent component but in my case, I am navigating to the parent eagerly. There seems to be no error in the console either. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `<ng-content></ng-content>` into `Parent` component's template.

Comment: I am not aiming at projecting content inside the child from the parent. I'm just trying to code the parent HTML as: <child></child> <div>....</div>